# knowning how much time is left before cron weekly runs?

Tags: linux, debian, cron

I am on debian 6.

Any way to see how many days are left before the cron weekly starts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system crontab is usually defined in `/etc/crontab/`.  It's here that the time interval for cron.weekly, cron.daily, etc is defined.  My `/etc/crontab/` looks like:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user command
 17 * *   *   *   root cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
 25 6 *   *   *   root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
 47 6 *   *   7   root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
 52 6 1   *   *   root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

So my cron.weekly will run at 6:47 on the 7th day of the week.

Edit:
The above information only applies to scripts in the /etc/cron.weekly directory.  As pointed out by [Iain](https://serverfault.com/questions/235354/knowning-how-much-time-is-left-before-cron-weekly-runs/235361#235361), @weekly is defined to run at midnight on Sunday.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by doing this on the command line:

`cat /etc/crontab`

Somewhere in this file, you should see a line like this:

`# m h dom mon dow user   command`

This describes the field order for each line below it. Otherwise, it's a whitespace-separated list, where each field goes in this order:

Minute, Hour, Day of Month, Month, Day of Week (where 0 or 7 is sunday and 6 is Saturday), Username to run command as, and Command to run.

There should be a line that ends in cron.weekly. This is your weekly run. By default this runs in the early hours of Sunday morning.

Also, try running this on the command line:

`man crontab`

Comment: Actually, `man 5 crontab`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `@weekly` is equivalent to `0 0 * * 0`  so it runs at midnight on Sunday.